# Run a search-replace with multiple passes in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file which has some tab-formatted tables, e.g.

```
Num     Name    val1    val2
1       Str     bar     baz
2       Dex     foo     bar
3       Con     foo     foo
```

(Apparently some people did not read my description and so were confused, so to clarify: this does not represent real data. The data is fake, only the format is real. Assume nothing about the data except that it does not contain `\t` characters.)

I want to convert it to a wiki's syntax, in which tables look like

```
{| border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 align=left
|- valign=top
! Num !! Name !! val1 !! val2
|-
| 1 || Str || bar || baz
|-
| 2 || Dex || foo || bar
|-
| 3 || Con || foo || foo
|-
|}
```

I have a set of regex search/replaces to do most of this, but the top line using !! is wonky. I have the header adding a ! to the beginning of the first line, and then use the regex

`/![\t ]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/`

replacing it with

`!! \1 !`

and applying to all lines. This works, eventually, but as it is it only works once per line and I need to make up to a dozen passes. I would like to lower the number of clicks needed, since I expect to be doing this conversion repeatedly.

I'm pretty sure "true" regular expressions can't do this, since it involves an unknown number of capture groups which have to be left intact, so I expect a solution will make use of some other capability of Notepad++. If I'm wrong and this can be done with a common extension to regex engines, that would also be great.

Comment: What about recording it as a per-line macro, then playing it to the end of the document?

Comment: That would probably work. I know nothing about Notepad++ macros, though.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert all the data lines in one pass.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:(^\d+|\G)\h+(\S+))(\R)?`
- Replace with: `| $1 || $2(?3$3|-$3)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    (           # group 1
        ^\d+    # 1 or more digit at begiinning of line
      |       # OR
        \G      # restart from last match position
    )           # end group 1
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    (\S+)       # group 2, 1 or more non spaces
)               # end group
(\R)?           # group 3, any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
| $1 || $2      # pipe space content of group1 space double pipe space content of group 2
(?3         # conditional replacement, if group 3 exists:
    $3          # content of group 3
    |-          # pipe hyphen
    $3          # content of group 3
)           # end condition
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

---

#### Then, you can convert manually the header

Comment: As I said, I expect to be doing this a lot. Fixing the header manually is worse than my current approach.

Comment: Also, the table rows mostly do not start with numbers. Most are words, some are numbers, some start with special characters. Your answer is overly-specific and therefore wrong.

Comment: It also is pointlessly complicated in checking for any linebreaks; whether I was using Unix or Windows I could just check for that. It also detects any type of whitespace as a separator when, as I specifically said, my tables are tab-separated. There is whitespace within entries of the table, so this would again be wrong.

Comment: @JacobKopczynski: If my “answer is overly-specific and therefore wrong.” may be it's because your question is not clear/too vague. Edit it and show real test cases. FYI `\R` stands for any kind of linebreak, you don't have to do any check before using it. You said you've used `[\t ]+`, that trictly  the same that `\h+`. Once you have the result I gave, you just need to replace the first line with a very basic regex. You said you do it in dozen steps, with my solution the whole job is done in 2 steps. If you prefer your solution, then do it.

Comment: I gave a very clear description of my data format. You ignored it and assumed the dummy data example was a description, which it was not.
Also, your comment is also incorrect; it would require manual intervention for *each table* to replace `|` in the the first line with `!`, which would require far more than 2 steps.

Comment: @JacobKopczynski: If you don't want my solution, do it yourself!

Comment: You did not give a solution. You gave a procedure which is a) wrong and b) slower than what I described as my current method.